# How do I get Illustrator to export to the same pixel dimensions as my Photoshop file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I have a Photoshop file that is 7016X9933 pixels.

[image: Photoshop image dimensions]

I have an Illustrator file that I want to use to generate some line art for the above Photoshop file. What I want to do is be able to export PNG files with transparency at the exact same pixel dimensions as the Photoshop file. This makes it very easy for me to coordinate positions and scales between the two files.

Unfortunately, for reasons I can't understand, I can not get Illustrator to export into the correct pixel ratio:

[image: Stupid Illustrator changing pixels]

Even though the Illustrator file has the correct dimensions in the "Original" section of the save for web interface, it changes the output dimensions to 7016X8192.

I have looked everywhere for dpi settings and other issues, but I can not get Illustrator to export in a direct 1 to 1 correlation to the original pixel dimensions.

**How do I get illustrator to export my image at 7016X9933 to match my Photoshop file dimensions?**

Comment: both photoshop and illustrators save for web have limit to exporting the size not more than 2(13) = 8192px; to overcome this problem you'll have to use export as option rather than save for web because such big files only being used for printing (not for web :D)

Comment: Unclick the "clip to artboard" option.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY, If I unclick the "clip to artboard option", then it only exports an area that exactly fits the lines being saved, no more. In other words, it forces a smaller image.

Comment: @Mr.Online, If I use the "export" option, it doesn't give me any options for image size or whether or not to save the whole artboard, and it defaults to only saving an area that is trimmed to just the particular lines being saved. Is there no way to save the whole artboard page as a PNG at the resolution I need?